# Possible to have different implementations for template header?

Tags: c++

If I make a comparator class that has a template header;

```
template <typename Type>
int operatorCmp(Type v1, Type v2);
```

Would it be possible to make a few different operatorCmp implementations in the cpp file which take, say, instances of a class and nodes etc? Would the compiler automatically use the right implementation of operatorCmp based on the arguments?

Comment: It was not clear from this snippet, but you are using a template method on a class. Method overloading will allow you to have multiple `operatorCmp` methods easily enough, but some more code of what you tried and what didn't work would make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler firstly tries to use non-template function, so if you make non-template comparator, compiler will use it.

Also you can do a partial specialization of template:

```
template<>
int operatorCmp<MyClass>(MyClass v1, MyClass v2);
```

It will be C++-way to create comparator

Comment: Nitpicking: the example you gave is a *full* specialization. Partial specialization would be like `template<class T> int operatorCmp<vector<T>>(vector<T> v1, vector<T> v2)` and this doesn't work with functions, just with structures/classes.

Comment: Ok, that looks completely unfamiliar but I'll do some research on that- thankyou...

Comment: The other thing I was thinking of was making a struct with comparators inside it. But tricky to return a value from that

Comment: You should make a functor - structure with overloaded operator() - it's an usual way to make a comparer